# Duplicated Magento Flat Rate module not showing on Checkout Page

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm new to magento and i'm trying to create 5 Flat Rates. I followed the instructions on http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/shipping/duplicating_flat_rate_shipping_module

The flat rate modules are showing on the admin page as expected and values has been set on the Shipping Methods configuration screen. "Enabled" is set to yes. Prices has been set.

The flat rate modules is showing on admin but not on the checkout page. Please note that there are no errors on the error-logs.

I'm using Magento 1.7.0.2

Comment: i also installed matrixtable rates and it does not show on available shipping methods even though it is ACTIVE

Comment: Have you cleared all Magento cache?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your shipping tablerate is not correct. (There's no condition to show this method).
Look at 'shipping_tablerate' table on you database.

Also, if you want two or more flatrate method create an extension to simplify your work.
Use this guide to create the extension:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/shipping/create-shipping-method-module

It too difficult have many flatrate shipping methods with 1 tablerate...

Comment: i'm gonna check the table. i'll comment again once i found something